# validate date of birth in MVC asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i'm having difficulties to validate date of birth. the user should select a date from the calendar. once the user click on validate. it should be able to determine if it is over 18 or under 18.  im new in mvc. any help? what statement should i insert to validate the dob (under or over 18)
here what i have tried:
Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(Information information, string buttonType)
    {
        if (buttonType=="Register")
        {
            var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(information.Surname + Environment.NewLine + information.DOBP + Environment.NewLine + information.Email + Environment.NewLine + information.Gender + Environment.NewLine + information.Tel);
            var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
            return File(stream, "text/plain", "Registration.txt");
        }
        if (buttonType=="Validate")
        {


        }
        return View(information);



    }
```

Comment: You can use subtract method of datetime.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.subtract?view=netframework-4.8,    https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/calculating-date-difference-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: @GauravChauhan can you please help me in term of code?

Comment: OT are you sure the surname contains only ASCII (read: non-accented Latin) characters?

Comment: hello hans yess

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same using Javascript .Check the link [Link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/118272/is-date-18-years-old) for javascript check .After checking the value you can validate in browser itself.Why to perform such actions in code behind ?Is there any need of such activity to performed code behind?

Comment: Link-only answers are typically not acceptable here.  Post the relevant code in your answers.  Additionally, this is more of a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Bhav

Here is a code example I am using some where in m code. Hope it helps you.

```
public bool IsValidDOB(DateTime date)
    {
        bool  objResult = null;
        try
        {
            if ( date < System.DateTime.Now )
            {
                DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
                int age = now.Year - date.Year;
                if (date > now.AddYears(-age)) age--;
                if (age>=18)
                objResult =  true;
                else
                    objResult =  false;
            }
            else
            {
                objResult =  false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            objResult = new  false;
            Core.Logger.AdminTrace.Logger(Core.Logger.LogArea.BusinessTier, ex);
        }
        return objResult;
    }
```

Comment: `if(targetDate <= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-18)) { // person is 18 yrs or older }`

Comment: hello Rajan where should i placed it on my mvc project ? on controller or in the view or model ..im new

Comment: @bhav you can call it in a controller but it will be wise to call it from some other class in business layer if you have it.

Comment: @RajanMishra how to call in the controller..?

Comment: bool isvaliddob= new className().IsValidDOB(dob);    Now write this in controller and use above method from another class.